# special case of constraint satisfaction efficient solution

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, constraints

I'm trying to solve a special case of the general constraint satisfaction problem in java.

Basically I have multiple variables, each one taking discrete values, and every variable is defined by the set of all possible values it has (think of it like an enumeration in Java, that would help).

I also have multiple groupements of conditions (think of a condition as a system of multiple equations on the variables, and they are all unary constraints: in other words of the form variable = possible value), the goal is to find if there's a set of variable values that satisfies at least one condition from each group (it might satisfy multiple ones from the same group). I will call this particular set a solution. What I'm looking for is all possible solutions.

The only Idea I have so far is basically brute force.

**This is a concrete example so things are clearer:**

- `s = {a,b,c}, v = {1,2,3}, n = {p,k,m}`.
- *First condition group:* 
  `c1 = {s=a and v=2}, c2 = {s=b}.`
- *Second condition group:*
  `c1={n=p and v=2}`.
- *Third condition group:*
  `c1={s=a and n=p}, c2 = {s=c}`.

In this situation, if we take `(s=a,v=2,n=p)`: it satisfies the first condition of all three groups, and is, therefore, a solution to the problem.

`(s=b,v=2,n=p)` however is not a solution, because it doesn't verify any of the third group's conditions. In fact, the number of possible solutions here is 1.

Please note that the conditions within a group are not necessarily mutually exclusive.

Any insight into a possible way to go more efficiently than by brute force be it a data structure or an algorithm would be great since I will have to solve millions of such systems of quite the number of variables (thirty variables tops of around 15 values each, and a hundred such conditions tops).

---

**Edit1: Data Constraints**
If `N` is the number of variables each problem will have then `N<=30`.

If `|V|` is the maximum number of elements a variable `V` can have, then I know that `Max(|Vi|)<=15` for every variable `Vi` in a problem.

I also know that if `C` is the number of constraints per problem, then `C<100`.

Lastly, I know that statistically speaking, the number of solutions for the problem will be small, meaning that most problems will have one single solution, and the likelihood of having more than 8 solutions is less than 99% of the time. For the sake of optimization, we can even assume that I'm never interested in any problem that has more than 10 solutions ever.

Comment: This is a bit broad. While i think i do understand the example, there is no fully formal description allowing very concrete recommendations. It depends on specifics if this is NP-hard or not; if counting / enumeration is exponential or not. Why would you need all solutions? Do you need these or only their number? There are probably exponentially many, which is a problem. The basic model is very naturally stated as SAT-model and can be solved *very very* efficiently (and some solvers are incremental which would allow enumerating all solutions; while reusing their already gained *knowledge*).

Comment: This is a very small part of a bigger problem I'm working on, but I definitely need all solutions, as a matter of fact every set of solutions will take me to a new problem as if I'm building and going down a tree of some sort. But as I stated, the problem is not infinite, I know that the number of variables will always be less 30, the number of values each variable can take will always be less than 15, and I will never reach 100 conditions per problem. I will try to read about SAT problems maybe that's a path I can take.

Comment: Hard to follow. If there are ~ 10^8 solutions (beware the potential combinatorial explosion), you could not even check a tree of depth 2. So you probably want some specific solution (which is not a decision-problem anymore, but an optimization one)

Comment: I know that, please see the edited part, I'm not interested in solving the general problem at all, I know that it's potentially NP-Hard, I'm just looking for a way to work within the constraints I have and based on the data I know about my input. It's true I formulated the problem in an abstract form but that's just for the sake of explaining it in a clearer manner.

Comment: Given that edit/assumptions (although i'm still sceptical about the number of solutions), nothing will beat SAT-solvers. So i recommend trying that route.

Comment: I am reading about them at the moment, any idea about what particular ones are good in java or what modulo theories would be more adequate to my problem ?

Comment: Pure SAT, not SMT. Every good one is implemented in C/C++. You can prototype with SAT4J, but for raw speed you would want to wrap some others. There is a yearly [competition](http://www.satcompetition.org/) which can provide some candidates. Look out for incremental-support. And be careful interpreting the competition results as i would think, more simple solvers (e.g. not that much inprocessing) will be faster for your (more simple) problem, while these competitions have some really really hard problems. But that's guesswork.

Comment: Will read about it for two or three days but I think that could work from what I've read so far. Thanks.